# write to specific cell datatable csvfile

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, .net-3.5

I know there is a lot about this but i just can't find a solution to my problem. Ive got this assignment to add some function to an very old system. It reads values from a csv-file and compare it to the result of a barcode scan.

```
searchResultLabel.Text = foundRows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
```

This code works fine and writes the data of row 1 and cell 2 to a label. But what i now want to do is add the value "X" to row 1 and cell 3. How do i do that? Ive tried a lot of different things i found but non of it works. I am using visual studio 2008, .net 3.5 and am coding to a Windows CE 5.0 device.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try =>  foundRows[0].ItemArray[2]="X";

Comment: yes, nothing happend :( Maybe i have to say that it should write or update the file in some way?